# ejabberd fail connection mysql

Tags: mysql, ejabberd, instant-messaging

My ejabberd.log:

```
2018-05-15 21:40:05.965 [error] <0.414.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:950 p1_mysql_conn: post_start error connect_failed

2018-05-15 21:40:05.965 [info] <0.414.0>@ejabberd_sql:connecting:339 mysql connection failed:
```

** Reason: connect_failed
** Retry after: 30 seconds

```
MySQL server:

sql_type: mysql

sql_server: "ejabberd"

sql_database: "ejabberd"

sql_username: "ejabberd"

sql_password: ""

sql_port: 3306
```

default_db: sql

sql_pool_size: 10

new_sql_schema: true

admin:

```
user:
```

##  - "admin@localhost"

```
  - "admin@server"
```

s2s_shaper: fast

modules:

mod_admin_update_sql: {}

mod_roster:

```
db_type: sql

default: always
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsCtD.png)

Comment: So without any more details, I'm going to guess that the problem is the MySQL server isn't running.

Comment: server is run, in uniform server portable(wamp). how can i verify this user is running?

Comment: And yet, I have no other details to go on. Maybe providing some code where the problem is happening would help.

Comment: ok, how can i verify this user and password it is correct?

Comment: Can you connect through a separate MySQL client using the same settings? If so, the settings are presumably okay and the server is running, so that's a good sign it's the code. Using example code that maybe came with the library can you connect with the same settings? If so, that would suggest it is something specific to your code. Try basic tests as much as possible to narrow the issue down, and then provide the relevant code (if it is code) that is still failing.

Comment: i do connect through a mysqlodbc, the connectio is successful on is user ejabberd, problem it is in code ejabberd.yml. thank man @Anthony

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/databases/mysql/ in document ejabberd in the same sequence if you only want to migrate the data, do not mention authentication ## auth_method: sql for the backend.

```
1. Create ejabberd user
2. Create ejabberd database 
3.  test the user and database
4. adapt MySQL schema whit command in mysql source C://path.mysq.sql;
5. you can show the list of SQL tables.
6. Adding MySQL connection configuration to ejabberd config file
7. Switch modules to use MySQL instead of Mnesia
8. Migrating data from internal database to MySQL
9. ejd2sql:export(<<"imserver.com">>, sql). //name server ejabberd
10. show data in schema work breanch.
```